# Nativescript how to change the size of the activity-indicator (iOS)

Tags: nativescript

Can the size of the activity indicator be changed in Nativescript iOS?

Also the color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sure can, I did something like this in my main view:

```
if (frameModule.topmost().ios) {
    var indicator = page.getViewById("indicator");
    indicator.ios.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
    indicator.ios.color = new colorModule.Color("#FFFFFF").ios;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked. For the next guy, it's actually UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge.

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my `app.css` which seems to do the trick for the color (I had no need to change the size yet):

```
ActivityIndicator {
  color: #4CC55B;
}
```